# EF - Do not increase the id value when using Seeding class

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am developing a project in .net core 2.1.1 and I am using a Postgree 12 database.

In my project I have a seeding class, and the objects created in the seeding are created normally in my database, but when I try to create a record in the bank after performing the seeding, I get an ID violation error.

> PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "PK_Linha"

this is my seeding class:

```
    public class SeedingService
    {
        //Populariza o BD

        private MesContext _context;

        public SeedingService(MesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Seed()
        {
            _context.Migrar();
            if ( _context.Linha.Any()) // este if serve para verificar se já existe dados no BD
            {
                // operação Any verifica se já existe algo na tabela x
                return; // se já existe retorna Obs: "O BD já foi populado"
            }

            Linha l1 = new Linha(1, "Linha 1", "descricao da linha1");
            Linha l2 = new Linha(2, "Linha 2", "descricao da linha2");
            Linha l3 = new Linha(3, "Linha 3", "descricao da linha3");


        // add os dados no BD
        _context.Linha.AddRange(l1,l2,l3);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

this is my model:

```
    public class Linha
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} é obrigatório")] // {0} é o campo Name
        [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3,ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter entre {2} a {1} caracteres")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter entre {2} a {1} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Estoque> Estoques { get; set; } = new List<Estoque>();
        public ICollection<OrdemProducao> OrdensProducao { get; set; } = new List<OrdemProducao>();
        public ICollection<LinhaEquipamento> LinhaEquipamentos { get; set; } = new List<LinhaEquipamento>();

        public Linha()
        {
        }

        public Linha(int id, string nome, string descricao)
        {
            Id = id;
            Nome = nome;
            Descricao = descricao;
        }
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
    public class LinhaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly LinhaService _context;
        private readonly UsuarioService _userContext;

        public LinhaController(LinhaService context, 
            UsuarioService userContext)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userContext = userContext;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var idUser = Int32.Parse(User.FindFirst("IdUsuario")?.Value);
            if (!await _userContext.VerificaPermissao( // se ele n possui permissão
                idUser, "Perm_Linha", ""))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SemPermissao", "Home", new { area = "" });
            }

            if (!await _userContext.VerificaPermissao( // se ele n possui permissão
                idUser, "Perm_Linha", "Sub_Deletar"))
            {
                ViewBag.PossuiDelete = false; // n possui
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.PossuiDelete = true; // possui
            }

            var list = await _context.FindAllAsync();
            return View(list);
        }

        //GET CREATE
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            var idUser = Int32.Parse(User.FindFirst("IdUsuario")?.Value);
            if (!await _userContext.VerificaPermissao( // se ele n possui permissão
                idUser, "Perm_Linha", "Sub_Criar"))
            {
                return StatusCode(403);
            }
            return View();
        }

        //POST CREATE
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Linha obj)
        {
            /*verifica se post é valido. Se  o js estiver desabilitado no navegador do usuario
            ele consegue dar post vazio, esse if serve para previnir isso*/
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(obj);
            }

            if (await _context.VerificaNome(obj.Nome, -1)) // se existe login
            {
                return Json("Erro: Este Nome já existe.");
            }

            await _context.InsertAsync(obj);
            return Json("Success");
        }
    }
```

This same situation was reported [here](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/536), but I was not successful in finding a solution for this.

would anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linha's Id is automatically discovered by EF Core and set up as an auto-incrementing key - that means that database is responsible for assigning ID values. However, in your seeding you are assigning the IDs yourself via a constructor (1, 2, 3). PostgreSQL does not update the auto-increment value, so the next Linha you try to insert will get an auto-generated key of 1, which conflicts with the seeded value.

To make this work, remove the id constructor of Linha and leave it uninitialized. This will make PostgreSQL generate auto-increment values for your seeded values as well, and all should work.

Comment: Thank you, solve my problem. Thanks for helping me.